# Is it possible to make Ember respond to `/app` when rootUrl is `/app/`

Tags: ember.js

In a Rails app with ember-cli, after login I'm redirecting to `/app`, where the Ember app is mounted. Unfortunately the ember app raises assert in `getHistoryPath`::

```
_emberMetalDebug.assert('Path ' + path + ' does not start with the provided rootURL ' + rootURL, rootURLIndex === 0);
```

Changing the redirect url to `/app/` works, but I'm wondering if there is an easy fix to make it accept `/app` as valid URL for the root path. User are very likely to type in manually /app and the result is a non-functional app. Changing the rootUrl to `/app` raises different assert in `detect()`:

```
_emberMetalDebug.assert('rootURL must end with a trailing forward slash e.g. "/app/"', rootURL.charAt(rootURL.length - 1) === '/');
```